# Hostgator php 5.4 upgrade in htaccess throws error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a project hosted on Hostgator. I need PHP 5.4 so, as they require, I add the following line to my .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

The issue is that with this line, any URL throws an error 404. Without this line, everything works fine - but with PHP 5.3 only.

I'm at a loss to understand how this line and error 404 are connected. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/php-5-4

Comment: Yep that's where I found the instructions. My account was open after the 1st of May, I copy/pasted the line as they indicate and the other lines in the . file work fine... Only this one fails completely.

Comment: This concerns shared hosting only. Are you sure YOU benefit from this 5.4 installation ? Check if basic phpinfo() if you can.

Comment: Yep I'm in shared hosting and the hostgator chat operator confirmed I should be able to use it.

Comment: @JohnWHS how can I use phpinfo exactly? Since I can't access pages when I try to enable php 5.4, I can only see it without the php5.4 line.

Comment: Indeed x) To me, the fact that it generates a 404 error means that the server now handles the .php files incorrectly. Anyway, those errors were recorded, so could you give us a error.log sample ? ^^ If you can't access it from your control panel, the hosting company should be able to give them to you.

Comment: That's the error in the log: `[Sun Jul 14 12:26:29 2013] [error] [client 2.25.223.80] File does not exist: /home3/(...myfolder...)/index.php/app`. So it looks like Codeigniter (which I'm using) is no longer routing anything because there is indeed no index.php/app file but a controller in my application folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's the php.ini file, probably located in your root user folder.  You have to remove/rename it.  There is a php.ini incompatibility between 5.2ish and 5.4.

Also, I've never been able to get AddType to work.  I've always had to use the older AddHandler.

On a side note, doing some more playing around in the php.ini, I figured out that register_globals=On was causing my 5.4 to hickup.  I thought it was shut off, but I guess not...  I changed it to off and my phpinfo page came alive.

And even more testing against my original php.ini file, I learned that: "allow_call_time_pass_reference = On" must be commented out...

Long story short, check your user php.ini files...